# How to rename an iCloud container?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I have created an iCloud container for my iOS app in Signing & Capabilities section of TARGETS named: **iCloud.myApp**

I have many problems with iCloud and I found in [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4878052-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started) that:

> The app’s bundle ID and iCloud containers must match and they must
> exist in the developer account. For example, if the bundle identifier
> is com.myDomain.myApp, then the iCloud container name should be
> iCloud. plus the bundle bundle id: iCloud.com.myDomain.myApp.

So the question is how and where to change it from **iCloud.myApp** to **iCloud.com.myDomain.myApp**?

Containers in Signing & Capabilities are not editable. I cannot find it in [CloudKitDashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard) as well. Or should I create a new container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit the name of a container once it is created, and you cannot delete it either (which is unfortunate; I filed a radar about that years ago).

If you already have `iCloud.myApp` created, you can use it! There's no real need to change to match the bundle identifier. It's merely a naming guideline. Apple lets you create and use any container ID as long as it's available. I'm using my own `iCloud.appName` identifier as we speak.

In your code, just point to your container id:

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.myApp")
```

...and then make sure it's selected in `Signing & Capabilities` in Xcode.

If you really want to create a new one with a new name, then you can do so in your Apple Developer account settings here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/cloudContainer

Comment: Thanks Clifton. It's interesting. So this tutorial that I have linked to is wrong about this. Do you know how Apple makes container IDs unique? If you have created iCloud.myApp, I cannot create new container with the same name? Or maybe 2 developers can create 2 containers with the same name, but each is tied to this developer?

Comment: And yes, I am using a container already. With "iCloud.myApp" naming convention. But this works fine on devices with one AppleID, but doesn't work on devices with another AppleID. And I am getting many errors. I was thinking it's because of the container name, but maybe it's something else :/

Comment: As far as I can tell, Apple enforces container ID uniqueness by giving you an error when you create it if the name already exists. I'm fairly certain those IDs are globally unique across all of CloudKit which is why Apple suggests the `com.example.yourApp` format.

Comment: Be sure to check your container permissions on `iCloud.myApp` and make sure both Apple IDs have full access to it. You can check those permissions in the CloudKit Dashboard. I currently share developer access to a container with multiple Apple IDs without any issues.

Comment: Thanks Clifton. I think by permissions you mean permissions for other people from my team. So other people could edit my iCloud container. What I meant is that iCloud sync works on my devices, but on other user's devices it doesn't sync. Users, not developers. I think I need to post a separate question for this.

Comment: @cliftonlabrum Ugh! The container name can't be changed or deleted? I was following a tutorial about CloudKit several months ago on the hackingwithswift website (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/33/overview), and the project name was Project-33. That name was used to create my iCloud container and now I am stuck with this name forever? Not fair!

Comment: Haha, yep, your test container is now a permanent addition to your CloudKit list. It's so ridiculous. The least they could do is let you hide them even if they aren't actually deleted on the back-end. I have like 30 containers and only actually use a few of them.

Comment: Hello @CliftonLabrum, during development iCloud container name is displayed last part of the identifier, It's not displaying a custom name, is there any issue?